# Django/Postgres primary key sequence

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have a Django application deployed on Heroku (free dyno) and I use Heroku Postgres as my database (Hobby Tier).

I been noticing that sometimes there are some gaps/jumps on the primary key numeration. For example, there was a jump from 162 to 195, from 237 to 270... But objects are not deleted in between this gaps. I can't really understand why this is happening.

Has anyone experienced something similar? What do you think? Is this problem related to Django, Postgres or Heroku?

Comment: [Sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) are not guaranteed to be gapless. Read the information in the section *Notes* at the linked docs to see why. FYI, sequences are also used by  `GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY ` when creating a table.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Thank you @AdrianKlaver. This [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_there_gaps_in_the_numbering_of_my_sequence.2FSERIAL_column.3F_Why_aren.27t_my_sequence_numbers_reused_on_transaction_abort.3F)  was also useful